# Send email after a customer change address in address book

Tags: magento2.3, address, dashboard

I need to send an email after a customer try to save a new address in his address book

Comment: are you talking about frontend?

Comment: Yes, in customer dashboard

Comment: Kindly check the answer I posted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below events for customer address.

```
<event name="customer_address_save_after">
    <observer name="customer_addres_after_save_event_observer" instance="Vendor\Extension\Observer\AfterAddressSaveObserver" />
</event>
```

OR

```
<event name="customer_address_save_before">
    <observer name="customer_address_before_save_event_observer" instance="Vendor\Extension\Observer\BeforeAddressSaveObserver" />
</event>
```

Comment: Could you please explain where to put this code, Thank you for your answer

Comment: You need to create events.xml into extension and put the code there.

Answer (score 0):

You should create `etc/frontend/events.xml` file in your module and post there event from [Dhiren Vasoya](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/44220/dhiren-vasoya) comment. Then create the class `Vendor\Extension\Observer\BeforeAddressSaveObserver` OR `Vendor\Extension\Observer\BeforeAddressSaveObserver` depending on your event name and send email inside the class. You can google a little and find the way how to send email with custom template and parameters.